# periodic function of x with period 2 and f(x) =|x|−x for −1<x≤1.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value

Let $f(x)$ be a periodic function in $x$ with period 2, and $f(x) =|x|−x$ for $−1< x≤1$.  Sketch the graph of the curve $y=f(x)$ in the interval $[−3,3]$.

$f(x) =|x|−x$ seems not to be a periodic function, though, so how can I solve the question? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you were given just that $f(x)=|x|-x$ then right, $f$ is not periodic. But here you're given that $f$ _is_ periodic. And it doesn't say "$f(x)=|x|-x$", it says "$f(x)=|x|-x$ **for** $-1<x\le 1$". So for example $f(3/2)=f(-1/2)=|-1/2|--1/2=1$.

Comment: Draw the graph for $-1\le x \le 1$. Then what should the graph for $1 \le x \le 3$ look like for $f$ be periodical? And so on and so forth. You could then be in a better position to write an equation for your function.

Comment: The problem DOES NOT SAY that |x|-x is a periodic function.  It says that f(x)= |x|- x for x between-1 and 1 (which has length 2) and then for other vaues of x repeats that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding David's comment, taking it step by step, first we have the function $f$ that's stated to be periodic with period 2, but we don't know what it looks like. Then, it's defined to be $f(x) =|x|−x$ for *just* the interval $(-1, 1]$.

Note that it's only for *that specific interval* that the function equals $|x|−x$. That can be evaluated to be this;
[image]

We've got what the function is for an interval of 2 units now*. We can use that as a repeating unit and make the rest of the graph.

Also note that the endpoints aren't both included in the graph, so you'll have to pay attention while completing it.

---

*Well, sort of. The leftmost point isn't in that '2 units'. But it'll work out when you think it through for the rest of the graph.

Comment: ok, then repeat it 3 time? from x=-3 to x=3

Comment: @Alex: you only have to repeat it twice, but yeah, that's the way to go. I assumed you could work out the rest of it, but I can help if you need.

Comment: why is that twice only? 1)x=-3 to x=-1    2)x=-1 to x=1   3)x=1 to x=3

Comment: @Alex: you'll have to construct the graph for the subsequent intervals [-3,-1] and (1, 3], so that makes just two repetitions. We've already covered (-1, 1].

Comment: thank you for your help